# Task Scheduler in Server 2016 Datacenter Edition Doesn't Run Automatically

Tags: windows, scheduled-task, windows-server-2016

We are migrating some applications and we use the Windows Task Scheduler as a tool.

Migrate from Server 2012 Datacenter for Server 2016 Datacenter.

I create the tasks in several ways, importing from task scheduler in Server 2012, manually or using PowerShell but the scenario is the same. Despite having the recurrence set for every 15 minutes and updating the "Next Runtime" field, the tasks do not start.

I did not find error log in the Service or Event Viewer of Windows.

Info About the Task:

Top privileges are checked and it's running a System Account. When you press Start it works perfectly. Before migration on Windows Server 2012 it worked correctly.

Task Print:
[image]

Some help?

Comment: See if anything here helps you: http://serverfault.com/q/631995/205065

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have same issue. Check this:
[Windows Server 2016 scheduled task schedule must be in future](https://serverfault.com/questions/821184/windows-server-2016-scheduled-task-schedule-must-be-in-future)
When I set Start time in future, the scheduler runs.

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault.  Can you make your answer stand on its own?  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers